# Как вывести окно поверх всех окон в Windows?

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, winapi

Нужно вывести окно поверх всех окон, для эффекта водяного знака. Возможно ли это сделать с помощью WPF без использования WinApi?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У окна WPF есть специальное свойство `Topmost`. Его нужно установить в `true`:

```
<Window x:Class="MySolution.MyProj.MainWindow"        
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MySolution.MyProj"
        Title="Sample" 
        Height="350" 
        Width="525"
        Topmost="True"> <!-- Вот тут -->
    <Grid>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

**UPD.** Не сразу понял, чего хотел добиться автор. Для того, чтобы сделать некоторое подобие "водяного знака" лучше использовать `Image`, а не окно.

Пусть наш водяной знак будет котиком. Думаю, все любят котиков :)

Изображение, с которым мы будем работать: `1.jpg`
[image: 1.jpg]

> А возможно ли сделать окно некликабельным? Чтобы можно было
>   взаимодействовать с объектами за ним

Это возможно для любого `UIElement`. Для этого нам понадобится свойство `IsHitTestVisible` установить в `false`. Ну и чтобы сделать изображение полупрозрачным, используем свойство `Opacity="0.2"`.

Таким образом, xaml-код будет выглядеть так:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp1"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Grid>
        <Button FontSize="35" Click="Button_Click">Hello</Button>

        <Image Source="1.jpg" Stretch="Fill" IsHitTestVisible="False" Opacity="0.2"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Теперь мы можем кликать на кнопку, и котик нам не будет мешать это делать)

Результат работы программы:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**P.S.** Обработчик событий в code-behind вызывает MessageBox с сообщением Hello.

Comment: А возможно ли сделать окно некликабельным? Чтобы можно было взаимодействовать с объектами за ним

Comment: @МаксимПоздеев аа, я понял, вы хотите сделать так, чтобы какое-то изображение было полупрозрачным и поверх всех элементов, создавая эффект водяного знака?